# What is my "service-account" for Google data store?

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore

I am following step by step getting started for Google data store for Python.

In one part it says, `replace service-account`.

I have been trying to search what it is. I tried client ID and project ID and it didn't work.

```
# configure your credentials
export DATASTORE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT=<service-account>
export DATASTORE_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE=<path-to-private-key-file>
```

Comment: Don't you think a quick search on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=google+service+account&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) would have been quicker than posting here?

Comment: @HoboSapiens don't you think I have already done at least 2 hours of searching and no response before asking here?

Comment: @HoboSapiens that shows you how to create a service account which I have done it already but what do I replace for the <service-account-> value ? the client id ? I already tried client id it fails...It is not clear what I replace <service-account> with

Comment: @HoboSapiens I had already seen that page but it is NOT helpful. your thinking is wrong.

Comment: That is the authentication for the API. AFAIK you have to create that account https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/prediction_service_accounts

Answer (score 0):

Service accounts for each use case are pretty well explained at https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount , including the distinction of whether your app is running on App Engine, Compute Engine, or elsewhere.

Since you have neither of the former in your tags, I imagine you're in the third case, so, as the page explains, you'll use the "Google Developers Console" web page to obtain credentials for the service account of your existing or newly-created "project".

Comment: I know how to create a service account, but the service account does NOT have a name, it has a client ID and a private key, and I have tried to put the client-id  (I am following tutorial step by step) it says autenation error

Comment: so basicly my question is, where I can find out the value to replace service account, the link you gave me shows me how to create a service account, what do I do after that !

Comment: here is the error I get : for running the sample https://gist.github.com/medyagh/8c2686c2efe725ae5dbc